# Spring not fetching certain fields from mysql database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data JPA to fetch Users from my database, then I map them to a DTO before returning to my controller.
However, the JPA repository is not fetching the date field and the email field.

I know my Mapper is not responsible for this as I logged the creation date of the original fetched entity, and it comes as null.

my getUser method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDto getUser(Long id) {
    User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
            () -> new TweeterException("No user with id " + id)
    );
    // For debugging purposes
    log.info("User creation date: " + user.getCreationDate());

    UserDto userDto = UserMapper.mapToDto(user);
    // For debugging purposes
    log.info("User dto creation date " + userDto.getCreationDate());
    return userDto;
}
```

My User entity:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, name = "username")
    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @Column(name= "password")
    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    @Column(name="email")
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Column(name="profile_image_url")
    @NotBlank
    private String profileImageUrl;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="biography")
    @NotBlank
    private String biography;

    @Column(name="creation_date")
    private Instant creationDate;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name="following")
    private Set<Integer> following = new HashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name="followers")
    private Set<Integer> followers = new HashSet<>();


    public void addFollower(Integer follower) {
        this.followers.add(follower);
    }

    public void removeFollower(Integer follower) {
        this.followers.remove(follower);
    }

    public void addFollowing(Integer following) {
        this.following.add(following);
    }

    public void removeFollowing(Integer following) {
        this.following.remove(following);
    }
```

My UserDto:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class UserDto {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String biography;
    private String profileImageUrl;
    private Instant creationDate;
    private Long followerCount;
}
```

I also have a Tweet entity and TweetDto, which works perfectly fine with the dates, so I'm not quite sure what is going on

Comment: Could you add Tweet entity & Tweet DTO? Also snapshots from the database highlighting the data in question.

Comment: Can you add code which you use to save user object to database? Can you verify that email and date are actually saved to database?

Answer (score 0):

I think that may be for **creationDate()** field you can try to use Java's **Date** data-type.
And also instead of *@Getter* and *@Setter* try **@Data** Annotation of Lombok,
For email field may be try only to put the *@Email* Annotation.
And check your Table names with the Entity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.date` for `creationDate` instead of `Instant`.
For email please verify column name.
Also add `@Table` annotation at class level with Db table name.
Ex:

```
@Table("name of table in database")
```

This is required only if you have different table name in database and tables names are case sensitive too.